# Does ActiveRecord handle locks and updates?

Tags: .net, activerecord, castle

ActiveRecord doesn't seem to cater for record locking and database updates. How does one synchronise updates in disconnected multi-user environments such as websites and web services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about Castle ActiveRecord (for .Net), I would believe you can use all the concurrency models that NHibernate support. For example with a version column:

http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/05/20/castle-activerecord-using-the-version-attribute.aspx